# Snap.svg drag group along path

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael, snap.svg

I need to do something along the lines of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzic/kKLtH/), but I with Snap.svg and with the ability to:

1. Drag the entire group along the path
2. Preserving spacing during the drag
3. Allow group drag from any group item
4. Support any number of group items
5. Support various different shaped paths

I started [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Z8B/3/) as a working starting point (and also posted below), but I'm at a loss at how best to attack the problem.

```
var paper = Snap('#panel');

var path = paper.path('M44.16,44.16 L44.16,44.16 L73.6,14.719999999999999 L132.48,73.6 L14.719999999999999,191.35999999999999 L132.48,309.12 L103.03999999999999,338.55999999999995 L44.16,279.67999999999995 L44.16,279.67999999999995')
.attr({
    stroke: 'gray',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    fill: 'none'
});

var c1 = paper.circle(103.03999999999999, 103.03999999999999, 15);
var c2 = paper.circle(44.16, 161.92, 15);
var c3 = paper.circle(73.6, 132.48, 15);

var cGroup = paper.g();
cGroup.add(c1,c2,c3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This quite a tricky one overall. Here's most of the solution which should at least set you off right as one possible method. For the distance checking, I used the code in the original fiddle, so credit to the person who wrote that, as its potentially tricky (and maybe worthy of its own SO question, I think it will need a tweak though).

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2kb5/24/) edit: You'll need to tweak to allow for starting position better.

Drag the circle to start it off, as I haven't set the start positions. You will want to adjust the elements starting positions, depending on whether you will zero offset them or whatever (otherwise you will need to allow for this when moving/transforming). You may also want to check for if the first/last element reaches the end and stops them all, so they all stop if one element reaches the path end.

It works by putting all the of the objects in a set, and attaching a handler to each of them (you could possibly just have one handler on the group, more elegant but may be a bit trickier).

We keep track of each elements index

```
this.data('index')
```

So when it comes to moving them along the line, we know where it is in the 'chain' and can offset to compensate, ie the following line...

```
 var whichDrag = this;
 ....
 mySet.forEach( function( el, i ) {

    var which = whichDrag.data("index") - i;
    pt = path.getPointAtLength(l + (which * spacer ));
    if( !isNaN(pt.x) && !isNaN(pt.x) ) { // check if over end
        el.transform('t' + pt.x + ',' + pt.y );
    };
 } );
```

Complete code...

```
var paper = Snap('#panel');

var spacer = 70;

var path = paper.path('M44.16,44.16 L44.16,44.16 L73.6,14.719999999999999 L132.48,73.6 L14.719999999999999,191.35999999999999 L132.48,309.12 L103.03999999999999,338.55999999999995 L44.16,279.67999999999995 L44.16,279.67999999999995')
.attr({
    stroke: 'gray',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    fill: 'none'
});
var pt = path.getPointAtLength(l);
    //e = r.ellipse(pt.x, pt.y, 4, 4).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#f00"}),
var totLen = path.getTotalLength();


var r1 = paper.rect(0,0,10,10);
var c3 = paper.circle(0,0, 15);
var c2 = paper.circle(0,0, 15);
var c1 = paper.circle(0,0, 15);
var l = 0;
var searchDl = 1;

var cGroup = paper.g();
cGroup.add(c3,c2,c1,r1);

var mySet = cGroup.selectAll("*");

start = function () {
    this.data("ox", +this.getBBox().cx );
    this.data("oy", +this.getBBox().cy );
    this.attr({opacity: 1});
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    var whichDrag = this;
    var tmpPt = {
        x : this.data("ox") + dx, 
        y : this.data("oy") + dy
    };
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    l = gradSearch(l, tmpPt);
    pt = path.getPointAtLength(l);
  //  this.attr({cx: pt.x, cy: pt.y});

    mySet.forEach( function( el, i ) {
        var which = whichDrag.data("index") - i;
        pt = path.getPointAtLength(l + (which * spacer ));
        if( !isNaN(pt.x) && !isNaN(pt.x) ) {
             //el.attr({cx: pt.x, cy: pt.y});
            el.transform('t' + pt.x + ',' + pt.y );
        };
    } );

},
up = function () {
    // restoring state
    this.attr({opacity: 1});
},

gradSearch = function (l0, pt) {
    l0 = l0 + totLen;
    var l1 = l0,
        dist0 = dist(path.getPointAtLength(l0 % totLen), pt),
        dist1,
        searchDir;

    if (dist(path.getPointAtLength((l0 - searchDl) % totLen), pt) > 
       dist(path.getPointAtLength((l0 + searchDl) % totLen), pt)) {
        searchDir = searchDl;
    } else {
        searchDir = -searchDl;
    }

    l1 += searchDir;
    dist1 = dist(path.getPointAtLength(l1 % totLen), pt);
    while (dist1
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  This is a very workable solution, though the use of an index to preserve order may prove problematic since in the application each circle may be added to the group out order.  To overcome this it would be nice to be able to find elements along the path and add to the group in the order found. Do you know how this might be accomplished?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, can you explain how the gradSearch function works?  It's a bit over my head.

Comment: I would be tempted to have those as standalone questions, with just the essential problem narrowed down without the rest of the code. If I get chance I'll try and do an update (I didn't write the gradSearch as mentiobed), but I actually think they are interesting problems in their own right which could be applied to a few scenarios. So I would be tempted to ask them separately (you may get some more interesting solutions).

Comment: Ok - makes sense.  I'll post some additional questions and look forward to your update.

Comment: Ok see this for the path item indexing related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811933/snap-svg-find-elements-along-path

Comment: I've now also added a question on determining drag distance along a path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812322/snap-svg-determine-drag-distance-along-a-path