# Snap.svg drag a group along a path and save position

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying Snap to manipulate SVG but I'm having some issues when dragging a group of elements along a path.

I modified this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/L2kb5/83/) that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773144/snap-svg-drag-group-along-path).

```
start = function () {
    this.data("ox", +this.getBBox().cx);
    this.data("oy", +this.getBBox().cy);
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    var tmpPt = {
        x: this.data('ox') + dx,
        y: this.data('oy') + dy
    };
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    l = gradSearch(l, tmpPt);
    pt = path.getPointAtLength(l);

    if (!isNaN(pt.x) && !isNaN(pt.y)) {
        this.transform('t' + (pt.x - this.data("ox")) + ',' + (pt.y - this.data("oy")));
    };
},
end = function () {
    console.log('End of drag');
}
```

I can drag the group, it stays where I drop it, but when I start to drag again, the group goes back to it's origin point and if I go crazy it starts to be really buggy.

I'm new to SVG, I tried some tutorials to learn but this stuff seams to be out of my league, I'd really appreciate some insights from you

Edit : It's better with my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/0L8qm7d4/9/), thanks for pointing that out Ian.

Comment: Its not very clear, the code in your question is different to the one in the fiddle, so not sure if that is just the original source. Can you add a jsfiddle to the bottom of the question with what you currently have, that matches the code above (or edit the code above to match).

Comment: Thank you @Ian, I forgot the most important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are resetting ox each time. In the previous examples, they used attr('cx') not ox, so they were always referencing the very original position of the shape to offset from. As you are resetting this each time, the difference will always be zero, so it resets to scratch. So you need a couple of modifications.

So lets all 'ox' the 'original position' before we do anything as our base.
And call 'sx' the 'starting position' that we figure out every drag start. We will need this to add 'dx' (the delta difference to add in a drag).

We can store the original position intitially...and then change the transform later to reference that original position, rather than the start position.

```
group.drag(move, start, end);
group.data("ox", +group.getBBox().cx);
group.data("oy", +group.getBBox().cy);

start = function () {
    this.data("sx", +this.getBBox().cx);
    this.data("sy", +this.getBBox().cy);
},

move = function (dx, dy) {

    var tmpPt = {
        x: this.data('sx') + dx,
        y: this.data('sy') + dy
    };

    l = gradSearch(l, tmpPt);

    pt = path.getPointAtLength(l);

    // We change this!!!
    if (!isNaN(pt.x) && !isNaN(pt.y)) {
       this.transform('t' + (pt.x - this.data("ox")) + ',' + (pt.y - this.data("oy")) );
};
},
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0L8qm7d4/13/)

Comment: Thank you very much, maybe it looks simple but I was blocked on that for so long, have a nice day and thanks again.