# React-Raphael Drag function on path

Tags: reactjs, raphael

I want to drag the circle on particular path in react-raphael. Anyone has any idea how i can achieve this. I googled a lot but unable to find a single reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could take a look at my answer for snap at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022363/snap-svg-drag-a-group-along-a-path-and-save-position and either adapt, or use snap.svg instead, which is almost the same as Raphael. jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/0L8qm7d4/13/